# Laravel 4.2 redirect back to orginal direction after adding items on cart

Tags: laravel

If I click on add to cart before logged in it took me to the login page, after a successful login i redirected back to my homepage but i want to redirect back to my view cart page with the item added to cart.Thanks in advance. Here is my filters.php file

[filters.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiqVw.png)

Here is my users controller

[userscontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueqJn.png)

Here is my Storecontroller

[enter image description here][3]

Here is my store controller code

class StoreController extends BaseController {

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('postAddtocart', 'getCart', 'getRemoveitem'))); 
}

public function getIndex(){
    return View::make('store.index')
        ->with('products',Product::take(4)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get());
}

public function getView ($id) {
    return View::make('store.view')->with('product',Product::find($id));
}

public function getCategory($cat_id){
    return View::make('store.category')
        ->with('products',Product::where('category_id', '=',$cat_id)->paginate(3))
        ->with('category', Category::find($cat_id)); 
}

public function getSearch() {
    $keyword = Input::get('keyword');

    return View::make('store.search')
        ->with('products', Product::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' .$keyword. '%')->get())
        ->with('keyword', $keyword);
}

public function postAddtocart() {
    $product = Product::find(Input::get('id'));
    $quantity = Input::get('quantity');


    Cart::add(array(
        'id'=>$product->id,
        'name'=>$product->title,
        'qty'=>$quantity,
        'price'=>$product->price    
    ));



    return Redirect::to('store/cart');
}

public function getCart() {
    return View::make('store.cart')->with('products', Cart::content());
}

/*public function getRemoveitem($rowid) {
    $rowId = Cart::get($rowid);
    Cart::remove($rowId[0]);
    //dd($product->rowId);
    //Cart::remove($product->rowid);
    return Redirect::to('store/cart');
}*/


public function getRemoveitem($rowid){
    Cart::remove($rowid);

    return Redirect::to('store/cart');

}

/*public function getCheckitem($rowid){
    Cart::search(array(
            'id' =>$rowid
        ));
    return Redirect::to('store/cart');
}*/

public function getContact(){
    return View::make('store.contact');
}
```

}

Comment: show me your login method  code

Comment: My login and log out code on users controller:


 public function postSignin() {
  if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
   return Redirect::intended('/')->with('message', 'Thanks for signing in');

  }

  return Redirect::to('users/signin')->with('message', 'Your email/password combo was incorrect');
 }


 public function getSignout() {
  Auth::logout();
  Session::flush();
  return Redirect::to('users/signin')->with('message', 'You have been signed out');
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

In your Login function you can

```
     return Redirect::intended('/default');
```

`/default` is a View that will be loaded if there is no intended page (when the user press the login button for exemple and then login , he will be redirected to `/default`

Comment: It is going to to my homepage whatever i do.but i want to go to cart page when i click on add to cart, it will go to the login page and when i login i want it to go to the cart page and i want the item to be added on cart but it is going to my homepage which i dont want..